# forEach to return value without a conditon

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have this array and I'm looping through it and I just want it to return the elements of the array without any condition I've seen in some examples of forEach loops returning something only when a certain condition is met.
Here is my code:

```
let tickets = ['Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A18',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A3',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1']

let ticket = tickets.forEach(ticket => {
    return ticket
});
 console.log(ticket); // undefined why?
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return a value, use `map` instead

Comment: for primitive values, you could slice the array.

Comment: Just reading the docs on `forEach` would have made this question unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to accomplish. But if need to combine all `tickets` elements in one `string`, here's the code:

```
let resultString = "";
tickets.map(singleTicket => {
    resultString += singleTicket + " ";
});
```

Comment: I want every single ticket in that array returned using `return`

Comment: You want them where? Printed in console?  In both cases that I've provided `ticket` will contain every single element of `tickets` array.

Comment: I don't want to print them in the console

Comment: I've updated my answer, so every single ticket will be stored in `singleTicket` variable.

Comment: @mots Here's what you need. All elements are combined in one string.

Answer (score 0):

From [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) :

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element; 
>   unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is
>   not chainable.  The typical use case is to execute side effects at the
>   end of a chain.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't return anything, you need to use map instead and can simply do it like

```js
let tickets = ['Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A18',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A3',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1',
'Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1']

let ticket = tickets.map(ticket => {
    return ticket
});
console.log(ticket);
```

`return` inside `forEach` acts like a `continue` statement, deferring the execution of the later statements and executes the next iteration.

However if you simple want to return all the elements of the array as they are, you might as well not use anything and just use the original array

Comment: @mots, what are you looking for exactly

Comment: I want return the result like this: 
`Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1`
`Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A1`
`Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A18`
`Follow link to download your ticket https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/ticket.html?ticket_number=201711297A3`

Comment: loop through that array and return each individual element inside that array. I dont't want to create another array. That's exactly what map() does

Comment: I wrote that response poorly. I could do that using `toString()`. I want each single element

Comment: array gives you each single element, how exactly do you want to use them